# Echoing vars from PHP to JavaScript and changing one field based on another field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am developing a website based on aviation, and one engine I run on my website, called SimBrief, must include the code below so that I can send the specifications along with the aircraft and registration.

```
<script>
var acdata = {};
acdata["reg":"YU-APA"]=['{icao":"A319","name":"A319-132","engines":"V2527\/A5","cat":"M","equip":"SDE2E3GHILORVWY","transponder":"H","pbn":"PBN\/B1D2D3","maxpax":"144","oew":92.48391898655717,"mzfw":128.9704233781548,"mtow":149.9143382857184,"mlw":137.78891386555,"maxfuel":42.086245851093594}'];
acdata["reg":"YU-APH"]=['{icao":"A320","name":"A320-232","engines":"V2527\/A5","cat":"M","equip":"SDE2E3GHILORVWY","transponder":"H","pbn":"PBN\/B1D2D3","maxpax":"174","oew":95.98926895529675,"mzfw":134.4819799327768,"mtow":162.0397627058868,"mlw":142.1981591092476,"maxfuel":42.086245851093594}']; 
</script>
```

Where YU-APA is an Airbus A319 and YU-APH is an Airbus A320.

```
<tr>
  <td>Aircraft:</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="type" id="Aircraft" value="<?php echo "{$schedule->aircraft}"; ?>">                                                 
      <?php
      $equipment = OperationsData::getAllAircraftSingle(true);
      if(!$equipment) $equipment = array();
      foreach($equipment as $equip){
        echo '<option value="'.$equip->icao.'">'.$equip->icao.' - '.$equip->name.'</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Registration:</td>
  <td><select class="form-control" name="reg" id="Registration">
    <option>YU-APA</option>
    <option>YU-APB</option>
    <option>YU-APC</option>
    <option>YU-APD</option>
    <option>YU-APE</option>
    <option>YU-APF</option>
    <option>YU-API</option>
    <option>YU-APJ</option>
    <option>YU-APH</option>
    <option>YU-APG</option>
    <option>YU-ARA</option>
    <option>YU-ALN</option>
    <option>YU-ALO</option>
    <option>YU-ALP</option>
    <option>YU-ALT</option>
    <option>YU-ALU</option>
    <option>YU-ALV</option>
    <option>YU-AND</option>
    <option>YU-ANI</option>
    <option>YU-ANK</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
```

How can I make so that when I select "Airbus A319" in the Aircrafts dropdown, the YU-APA shows up in the Registrations dropdown, and when I select A320, the YU-APH appears? Obviously, there are more registrations for one aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Aircraft").change(function() {
        if($("#Aircraft").val() === 'A319') {
            $("#Registration").val('YU-APA').change();
        } else if($("#Aircraft").val() === 'A320') {
            $("#Registration").val('YU-APH').change();
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: You need to add a `value` attribute to your `Registration` field `<option>` tags. Also, instead of typing `A319` and `A320` (in the `if` statement), type whatever the `value` is for those planes.

Comment: And what if you have multiple registrations? I'm sorry, don't have experience with jQuery very much.

Comment: @SuadČobo What do you mean by multiple registrations?

Comment: There are multiple A319's in the fleet, and they all require a registration.

Comment: @SuadČobo so you have more than one `Registration` field?